# Is it possible to use Selenium from within a web app?

Tags: selenium

I am building a web site in Django that would scrape data from some site, so people could enter the site, set custom data filters and view scraped data in friendly format.

The problem is that `requests` and `beautiful soup` modules will not be enough for the scraping purposes, since I will also need some automation to be done (loading javascript or clicking buttons).

Since Selenium requiers a webdriver to be downloaded and put into a path, is it possible to use it from within web app? Like hosting the webdriver somewhere?

I am also open to solutions other than Selenium, if there are any.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you would want is a selenium grid server.

https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp

Basically you host it on some remote server and then you can connect to it and spin up web drivers remotely and use them in code as needed. It also comes with a handy interface for checking on current browser instances and even taking screenshots or executing scripts from the web ui.